# Sampling independently and uniformly at random vs sampling with fixed probability

Tags: binomial-distribution, sampling

Assume a universe $U$ with $n$ elements. Let $p$ be the fraction of elements in $U$ with some property $P$. The goal of this problem is to estimate $p$ using samples from $U$. Given input parameters $\varepsilon$ and $\delta$, we want our estimate $\hat{p}$ to have the following guarantee: $\Pr[ |\hat{p} - p| \geq \varepsilon ] \leq \delta$.

Standard Approach: sample a set $S$ of size $O(\frac{1}{\varepsilon^2} \ln (\frac{1}{\delta}))$ uniformly at random and independently from $U$, and then set $\hat{p}$ to be the fraction of the sampled elements with property $P$. Using Chernoff bound, we can show that $\hat{p}$ has the desired guarantee.

Now consider the following sampling process. Sample each element in $U$ with probability $q = \frac{1}{\varepsilon^2} \ln (\frac{1}{\delta})\frac{1}{n}$. Let the resulting set be $S$. Note that $\varepsilon$ and $\delta$ are input parameters to the process. So if it happens that $q \geq 1$, then the sampling process would store the entire universe, i.e., $S=U$. So assume $n$ is large enough, such that $q < 1$. Now set $\hat{p}$ to be the fraction of the elements in $S$ with property $P$. Does $\hat{p}$ still have the same guarantee as before? If so, then how does one go about proving it? Any pointers to the existing work would also be very helpful.

Comment: There will actually be less fluctuations in this sample, as you can see e.g. from the fact that as $q$ goes to $1$ you have no fluctuations at all and get the precise value of $p$, whereas sampling $n$ times independently still leaves you with an error.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2807013/14578, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/92705/755, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/349634/2921.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: 1. What's $n$?  Is $n=|U|$?  Is it some arbitrary independent variable, where the goal is to find out for what values of $n$ the resulting estimate is good?  It might help to edit the question to state that.   2. Have you tried working through the same kind of analysis?  Have you tried finding the expectation and variance of $\hat{p}$, and then applying a Chernoff bound?  If not, you should give that a try and show your work.